# Performance improvement idea about saving large number of Objects into the dabatase

Tags: spring, database, performance, hibernate, websocket

My web application has one feature where it allows the user to send messages to all friends. The number of friends can be 100K to 200K. The application is using Spring and Hibernate.

It entails fetching the friends' info, building the message object and saving it to the database. After all the messages are sent (actually saved to the db), a notification will popup showing how many messages are sent successfully such as 99/100 sent or 100/100 sent.

However, when I was load testing this feature. It took an extremely long time to finish. I am trying to improve the performance. One approach I tried was to divide the friends into small batches and fetch/save each batch concurrently and wait on all of them to finish. But that still didn't get too much improvement.

I was wondering if there are any other ways I can try. Another approach I can think of is to use WebSockets to send each batch and update the notification after each batch and start the next batch until all the batches are sent. But how can the user still get the notification after he navigates away from the message page? The Websocket logic on the client side has to be somewhere global, correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check what tool you so long - sending messages or persisting those into the database (with 100k both willl)

Comment: @Antoniossss Both fetching the friends info and sending into the database took very long. There's no "sending messages". As soon as the message is saved to the db, it is "sent"

Comment: So you "Fetch it by hand" Well that is not going to fork fast as you are selecting 100k records than you are hydrating those, than you are processing, generating SQL etc etc. Its not going to be fast on single node - clustering is the answer. OR deltay DB operations and use message queue system to distribute data - Google cloud messaging can do this for you for free (to some extent). SO you send 1 message, and all interested parites are getting the data (as they are subscribed to the given channel)

Comment: @Antoniossss Thanks. Unfortunately, this is a legacy app and it might be difficult to integrate cloud messaging. How about the idea of websocket? The issue is how I can keep track of the status when the user leaves the page when using websocket.

Comment: @Antoniossss Also we would like to keep track of how many messages are "sent" successfully. At the end we need a popup saying something like 98/100 sent. Because when sending, some friends might not be your friend anymore. The data can change.

Comment: So you want to have 100k connection opened? Sure it is possible but rather not on single instance - again - clustering. For messaging app use message driven protocols  or PubSub eg XMPP.

Comment: @Antoniossss Not 100K connection. Will be 100K database queries. It's not a real time messaging app. The messages are saved in the db and the other end has to refresh the page to see the messages.